# What is the best way to get from Venice Mestre to Lido di Jesolo with a roadbike?

Tags: public-transport, transportation, italy, bicycles, venice

I will arrive in Venice by train at the Mestre station, from there I want to get to Lido di Jesolo with my roadbike. What are my options?

I was considering getting to Venice from Mestre on foot or bike using the bridge Via Libertá, and then taking the ship to Punta Sabbioni. Now this sounds doable, but I guess I can't bike or walk on that bridge!

Comment: You can put the bike in a train or a bus.

Comment: @mouviciel I don't know about the bus, but I had thought of the train. Do I have to pay a separate fare for the bike?! It would be nice to know if there are other possibilities, especially ones utilizing the roadbike.

Comment: Unfortunately, I have no information about the train+bike thing in Italy. I only found a link to trenitalia: [Travelling with your bicycle](http://www.trenitalia.com/cms/v/index.jsp?vgnextoid=872311e84819a110VgnVCM1000003f16f90aRCRD)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here](http://translate.google.com/translate?hl=en&langpair=it|en&u=http://www.piste-ciclabili.com/comune-venezia) you can find a map of bike-allowed street. Probably it will be longer but there is a possibility to go to Punta Sabbioni by using only the bike.

Hope it can help!